# Laravel faker repeating same name

Tags: laravel, faker, php-faker

Laravel framework: v8.12
fakerphp/faker: v1.9.1

If I change the `'faker_locale' => 'en_SG'`,
The `$this->faker->name();` in the factory always generates `John Doe` or `Jane Doe`, nothing else.

How can I get other names in my db seeding?

Tried changing the locale gives variety of names.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the locale you're using doesn't have any predefined fake names. You can check the code here: https://github.com/FakerPHP/Faker/blob/main/src/Faker/Provider/en_SG/Person.php

Compare this to the locale `en_US` here: https://github.com/FakerPHP/Faker/blob/main/src/Faker/Provider/en_US/Person.php to understand the difference.
The only way to make it work is to contribute to the package by improving it with fake names for this locale. Or you need to use some other locale that has enough fake data.